# Undefined Index

Tags: php

Скажите пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку?

> Notice: Undefined index: Enter in /home/Maks5/weston-rp.ru/public_html/index.php on line 4

Строка:

```
if($_SESSION['Enter'])
```

Comment: Определить в массиве $_SESSION поле Enter, либо сначала проверить существование элемента - isset($_SESSION['Enter'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нужно в начале кода использовать функцию** [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['Enter']='ok';
if(isset($_SESSION['Enter']))echo 'Welcome';
```

Answer (score 1):

Оно не находит такой индекс. Сначала нужно создать его. А потом уже запрашивать. Или если Вы хотите проверить существует ли он вообще, то пишите `if(isset($_SESSION['Enter']))`