# Выводит ошибку Notice: Undefined index: index.html in C:\server\data\htdocs\сайт\url.php on line 11

Tags: php, html, css, post, form

не могу понять в чем ошибка вот код:
Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>I_try</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>

        <h1>

            What is this?

        </h1>
        <div class="block">
            <form action="url.php" method="post">

                <input name="url" type="url">

                <input type="submit">

            </form>
        </div>
        <br>

    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Css style.css

```
body{
    background: url(../img/wtf.jpg) no-repeat center top/cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Php url.php

```
<?php 

$url = "https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=84a8sss";

$filee = fopen('text.txt', 'r+') or die("Error 404");

$inputt= fwrite($filee, 'это что за фигня');

$good = fwrite($filee, "$urll"); #тут не могу понять как сделать так чтобы он записывал в файл

$here = file('text.txt'); 

$urll = htmlspecialchars($_POST['url']); 

fclose($filee)

 ?>
```

Comment: наверное вы хотите получить все же `$_POST['url']` ?

Comment: teran спасибо большое и у меня последняя просьба я сейчас изменил php мне нужно чтобы это записывало в текстовый документ можете посмотреть заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Undefined Index](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501892/undefined-index)

Comment: вы сначала пишите переменную в файла, а только потом ее инициализируете значинем.